# Find all positive integers k so that...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, rational-numbers

Let
$$
P = \sqrt{\frac{3\times10^{n}}{k}}
$$
Find all $k$ positive integers so that $P$ is rational and belongs to $(0,1)$ for all $n$ positive integers.

Comment: You want to find all *pairs* of positive integers $(k,n)$? Because no single $k$ will work with every $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I edited. I had misplaced the numerator and denominator. I need to find all k's for all n's.

Comment: Still no such $k$.

Comment: @Gae.S.Why? Can you show me? if $n=1$, $k$ needs to be $30^3$. If so, $P=1/30$

Comment: If $n$ is odd then $k=30\cdot t^2$ for any $t>10^{(n-1)/2}$ otherwise if $n$ is even you have $k=3\cdot t^2$ for $t>10^{n/2}$

Comment: For any $k$, it's easy to see that for $n$ large enough $P>1$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you, as you wrote, asking for the solution set { k is positive integer : for all positive integer n, P(k,n) is rational in (0,1) }?

Comment: If you fix any $k$, then the numerator grows unboundedly to $+\infty$, so $P$ can't be in $(0,1)$ for all $n$.